# Javascript: User login in local storage, how to set active user?

Tags: javascript, authentication, local-storage, active-users

i successfully made a user login form with html en javascript. The user can register and login. But i need to set a class when the user is logged in so they can see a custom navigation. 
My html code is as followed: `               
                        
                            
                                account_circle

```
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row margin">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <i class="mdi-social-person-outline prefix"></i>
                            <input id="logname" type="text">
                            <label for="logname" >Username</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row margin">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <i class="mdi-action-lock-outline prefix"></i>
                            <input id="logpw" type="password">
                            <label for="logpw">Password</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <div class="center-align"><a id="login_btn" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit"  onclick="check()">Login</a></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <div class="center-align"><a href="register.html" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Registreer hier</a></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                </form>`
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();

});

// naam en pas register
var regiName = document.getElementById('regname');
var regiPw = document.getElementById('regpw');

function store() {
    localStorage.setItem('uName', regiName.value);
    localStorage.setItem('pw', regiPw.value);
}

function check() {


    var storedName = localStorage.getItem('uName');
    var storedPw = localStorage.getItem('pw');


    var userName = document.getElementById('logname');
    var userPw = document.getElementById('logpw');


    if(userName.value == storedName && userPw.value == storedPw) {
        alert('You are loged in.');
    }else {
        alert('Gebruiker of wachtwoord wordt niet herkend.' + userName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is security an issue? If this should go into the wild, you shouldn't do your security on the front end.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen no, this is a assignment for school and we need to work with front end.